# How do I start a node.js script in the foreground on raspbian boot?

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, cron, raspbian

My app lives at `/home/pi/app/app.js`

and node lives at `/home/pi/node-v0.10.28-linux-arm-pi/bine/node`

I've setup raspbian to login to the `pi` user automatically at boot, now I need to automatically run app.js in the foreground (since it requires input from a USB device).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://www.debian-administration.org/article/28/Making_scripts_run_at_boot_time_with_Debian

You could try something like (in a file /etc/init.d/nodejs)

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/nodejs
#
node /home/pi/app/app.js
exit 0
```